# Can anyone think of when a sub-request rewrite is useful?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I found that one of the main things that cause `.htaccess` rewrite rulesets to do seemingly bizarre things is when Apache decides to try to apply them inside a subrequest.  This is to the extent that I now always use the `[NS]` flag on my rules or use a prefix rule

```
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ}%{ENV:END} t|1             [NC]
RewriteRule ^                      -               [L]
```

(The %{ENV:END} bit just allows me to use E=END:1 to do the same as the V2.4 END flag.)

My Q is: *can anyone give me of a good usecase where I wouldn't want to do this?* (or alternatively where I would want to use the special **-U** or **-F** condition patterns).

I realise that there may be many that I haven't thought of, but the A tick goes to the first valid one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess the typical situations where you'd want to apply rewrite rules to subrequests are more or less the same as the one where you'd use symlinks inside your document root.

For a plausible example, let's say you're using Server Side Includes, and have a bunch of files scattered around with suffixes like `.html`, `.shtml` and `.htm`, and perhaps some uppercase variants of these too.  At some point, you decide to standardize on the `.html` suffix, and rename all your files accordingly.  But you still have a bunch of legacy code and links that use the other suffixes, and rooting them all out will take a while.

In that case, you might want a rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.s?html?$ $1.html [NC]
```

By applying this to subrequests too, you ensure that your Server Side Includes don't break because of the renaming.

Comment: Yup agreed; this is a good example, though one I've never seen used.  It also underlines to me that it's a pity that [nosubreq] was the default and that you had to explicitly enable it with [subreq] when you wanted to use a rule in a subquery.

Comment: A valid answer and the only one so the tick goes to you :-)  I had hoped for a few more, but as I thought: they're thin on the ground!